# What does broadcast +/- mean in /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: networking, debian

In `man interfaces` for `/etc/network/interfaces` on Debian:

> The static Method
>
> This method may be used to define Ethernet interfaces with statically allocated IPv4 addresses.
>
> Options
>
> broadcast
>
> broadcast_address
>
> Broadcast address (dotted quad, + or -). Default value: "+"

**What do `+` and `-` mean here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On *Linux*, when using the [*ip address*](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/iproute2/ip-address.8) command, which [*ifupdown*](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/ifupdown/interfaces.5) does use on Debian 10 (and 9 and perhaps a few former versions), rather than the [*ifconfig*](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/net-tools/ifconfig.8) command,  + and - for broadcast mean, after separating the *network* part of the IPv4 address (with a /xx address, the first xx bits, which will be left untouched) and the *host* part of the IP address (the remaining 32-xx bits) to set all *host* bits to resp 1 and 0 for + and - when computing the *broadcast* address. It's also possible to choose any arbitrary IP in this network to be used as broadcast (that's the dotted quad option). The resulting IP chosen from any of the 3 previous ways will be the reserved destination IP that (at least on Ethernet interfaces) will be associated to the broadcast link layer address (so ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff on Ethernet).

Here are a few examples:

```
# ip link add name test type dummy
# ip link set test up
# ip address add 192.0.2.5/24 broadcast + dev test
# ip address add 198.51.100.20/28 broadcast - dev test
# ip address add 203.0.113.130/24 broadcast 203.0.113.100 dev test

# ip -4 address show dev test
4: test: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.0.2.5/24 brd 192.0.2.255 scope global test
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 198.51.100.20/28 brd 198.51.100.16 scope global test
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 203.0.113.130/24 brd 203.0.113.100 scope global test
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
# ip route get 203.0.113.100
broadcast 203.0.113.100 dev test src 203.0.113.130 uid 0 
    cache <local,brd>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I wonder if this contradicts Bert’s answer who claims that a `+` found in `interfaces` tells `ip` respective `ifconfig` to use `netmasks` file.

Comment: Checking again: ip address doesn't use /etc, but indeed, ifconfig does look at /etc/networks. So this answer doesn't contradict the other. But (this might depend on version) ifup/ifdown runs ip addr, not ifconfig.

Answer (score 3):

The plus sign after the keyword `netmask` causes `ifconfig` to take the corresponding value from `/etc/init/netmasks`.

```
# ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.50 netmask +
```

Would tell `ifconfig` to look in the `netmasks` file for the subnet for this interface. The line would look something like:

```
192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

This is a leftover from the Sun days, most of the time you will have something like `NETMASK=255.255.255.0` in the configuration file for the network interface.

Comment: And the minus—what does that mean?